# Marmalade SDK - How to make data persistant after update

Tags: ios, marmalade

How do I keep the users data when they get an update.

I use the Marmalade SDK to develop an app and I saved the user data to bin files and text files, I used the ram:// prefix when saving the files.

If I delete the app and get it from the app store again with the could symbol It had lost all its user data. I would like to release an update that doesn't delete the users data. The app does not come with any user data files, the app creates them as you use it.

Edit: Marmalade is cross platform but my question is for iOS only and the app has been publish, I am asking with respect to an existing app.

Comment: What's the criteria for down voting :/ anyways it looks like I cant release an update for my app and keep my user data if I did not sore my data correctly.

Comment: For those who want to know, inspecting the log of a debug build of my app revels that saving to ram://userdata.bin had an absolute path ending in documents/userdata.bin and as such I am assuming my user data will be transferred when I release my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the app from the device, also removes it's sandbox. So any user data stored locally is deleted. This is expected behaviour.

If the user data comes from the web, then you just need to download it again.

Comment: how do I release an update for the iOS app without deleting the user data in the sandbox?

Comment: Does iCloud not backup user data?

Comment: @Desdenova thanks that's what I was looking for. I need to establish if my user data is saved in the documents folder and as such will be transferred in an update.

Comment: @Abizern thanks that helps. It is the deletion of my app that deletes the user files and does not necessarily mean the user data will be lost in an update.

Comment: No. And update occurs in place, so the sandbox is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [tutorial for dealing with files](http://www.drmop.com/index.php/2011/10/07/marmalade-sdk-tutorial-dealing-with-files-and-the-file-system/)?

I have never used that sdk but:

- `rom` for the read-only portion of your apps data area and is read only.
- `ram` for the writable portion of your apps data area. This drive is the only drive that is guaranteed to exist across platforms
- `rst` for a removable memory card on the phone or tablet
- `raw` for paths that will be passed directly to the underlying operating system without modification. (not supported on all platforms)
- `tmp` for a system temp folder, outside of the s3e data area. (system temporary folder and currently only available on iOS)

So maybe you could try rst:// and get the expected result?

Comment: Thanks but the app is publish I cant change how it saves user data, I want to release an update without deleting the users data for an existing app.